# uninitialized constant *ModelXYZ* in seeds.rb. Wrong config?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seed

I have some simple Rails 5 API models, e.g. class `Training`. Executing

```
Training.delete_all
```

works like expected from Rails console.
The exact same line of code results in

```
in `<main>': uninitialized constant Training (NameError)
```

when used (as first line) in *seeds.rb*.
I cannot guess why.

Comment: What command do you use to run your seeds?

Comment: well, inside RubyMine it is bash -c `"RBENV_VERSION=2.5.3 /usr/local/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec ruby PATH_TO_PROJECT/db/seeds.rb".` On command line just rails `db:seed`

Comment: Use `bundle exec rails db:seed` then to properly load the environment :)

Comment: very strange. Your suggestion helps on command line. It does not inside RubyMine. But if I run db:setup in RubyMine, it works, too. But not standalone only running db:seed. Seems to be a RubyMine specific problem additionally :(. And bundle exec is also called inside RubyMine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As established in the comments, using `bundle exec ruby db/seeds.rb` won't work as it won't prepare the environment (load all the models, etc.).

Proper way of running Rails seeds is by `bundle exec rails db:seed`.